# Exported VertexAI TabularModel model_warm_up fails when running docker

Tags: google-cloud-ml

Good Evening,

I have followed the instructions found here.

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/export/export-model-tabular

I trained the model on the Google Cloud Platform console
Then exported the model per the instructions. However when I run the `docker run` command I get the following:

```
docker run -v `pwd`/model-1216534849343455232/tf-saved-model/model:/models/default -p 8080:8080 -it us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/automl-tabular/prediction-server-v1

INFO:root:running uCAIP model server
2022-04-12 02:07:09.118593: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:85] Building single TensorFlow model file config:  model_name: default model_base_path: /models/default/predict

2022-04-12 02:07:09.118695: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:462] Adding/updating models.

2022-04-12 02:07:09.118703: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:573]  (Re-)adding model: default

2022-04-12 02:07:09.219134: I tensorflow_serving/core/basic_manager.cc:739] Successfully reserved resources to load servable {name: default version: 1}

2022-04-12 02:07:09.219153: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:66] Approving load for servable version {name: default version: 1}

2022-04-12 02:07:09.219159: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:74] Loading servable version {name: default version: 1}

2022-04-12 02:07:09.219172: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:31] Reading SavedModel from: /models/default/predict/001

2022-04-12 02:07:09.229531: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:54] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }

2022-04-12 02:07:09.241239: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA

2022-04-12 02:07:09.256079: E external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1575] OpKernel ('op: "DecodeProtoSparse" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: DecodeProtoSparse

2022-04-12 02:07:09.277522: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:202] Restoring SavedModel bundle.

2022-04-12 02:07:09.338428: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:151] Running initialization op on SavedModel bundle at path: /models/default/predict/001

2022-04-12 02:07:09.371063: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:311] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success. Took 151887 microseconds.

2022-04-12 02:07:09.373646: I tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/saved_model_warmup.cc:117] Starting to read warmup data for model at /models/default/predict/001/assets.extra/tf_serving_warmup_requests with model-warmup-options 

2022-04-12 02:07:09.573843: F external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.cc:44] Check failed: NDIMS == dims() (1 vs. 2)Asking for tensor of 1 dimensions from a tensor of 2 dimensions

2022-04-12 02:07:09.573843: F external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.cc:44] Check failed: NDIMS == dims() (1 vs. 2)Asking for tensor of 1 dimensions from a tensor of 2 dimensions

Aborted (core dumped)

INFO:root:connecting to TF serving at localhost:9000
INFO:root:server listening on port 8080
INFO:root:connectivity went from None to ChannelConnectivity.IDLE
INFO:root:connectivity went from ChannelConnectivity.IDLE to ChannelConnectivity.CONNECTING
INFO:root:connectivity went from ChannelConnectivity.CONNECTING to ChannelConnectivity.TRANSIENT_FAILURE
INFO:root:connectivity went from ChannelConnectivity.TRANSIENT_FAILURE to ChannelConnectivity.CONNECTING
INFO:root:connectivity went from ChannelConnectivity.CONNECTING to ChannelConnectivity.TRANSIENT_FAILURE
```

I am not sure what I did wrong, or what I need to change to fix it.

Thank you for your help, in advance.

UPDATE:

environment.json contents

```
{"container_uri": "us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/automl-tabular/prediction-server:20220331_1125_RC00", 
"tensorflow": "2.4.1", 
"struct2tensor": "0.29.0", 
"tensorflow-addons": "0.12.1", 
"tensorflow-text": "2.4.1"}
```

Comment: Does your model artifact contain an environment.json file? If you have not included container_uri in the environment.json file, can you please include the container_uri  in the file and try? Let me know if it's helpful or not?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar I have updated my question to include the text of the environment.json file

Comment: Hi @eharley_21  Could you try adding `europe-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/automl-tabular/prediction-server:20210820_1325_RC00` as your container-uri and check if it works?
Let me know if it’s helpful or not?

Comment: Hi @eharley_21 Could you confirm that whether adding `europe-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/automl-tabular/prediction-server:20210820_1325_RC00` as your container-uri resolved the issue or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused due to compatibility issues of the images with the models. prediction-server-v1:latest is always backward compatible with existing models without environment.json but it  is not forward compatible with new models that have environment.json.  To resolve this issue, following workarounds can be performed:

- If the model artifact contains environment.json (new models),  use
  `us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/automl-tabular/prediction-server:20210820_1325_RC00`
  or
  `europe-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/automl-tabular/prediction-server:20210820_1325_RC00`
  image in conatiner_uri in environment.json.
- If there is no environment.json, use  `europe-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/automl-tabular/prediction-server-v1:latest` this image is backward compatible with all models without environment.json.

Answer (score 1):

More general answer is, the `container_uri` field in your `environments.json` file should match exactly with the image you're pulling from the Google registry. After pulling that exact image, you will run that as a container on your local environment. So even though the documentation gets stale sometimes, this is the general logic.

E.g. if your `environment.json` says

```json
{"container_uri": "us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/automl-tabular/prediction-server:20221110_1525", "tensorflow": "2.8.0", "struct2tensor": "0.39.0", "tensorflow-addons": "0.16.1"}
```

then you first pull the image with

`docker pull us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/automl-tabular/prediction-server:20221110_1525`

and then run the container with

`` docker run -v `pwd`/model-7073468363762040832/tf-saved-model/example-model:/models/default -p 8080:8080 -it us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/automl-tabular/prediction-server:20221110_1525 ``

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem.  Even retraining an old model which had previously worked, now fail.  Taking the commented suggestion of Shipra Sarkar, I tried using package,

europe-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/automl-tabular/prediction-server:20210820_1325_RC00

Using this old package, I no longer get the error.